# how can I identify multiple callers from one same line in the callee?

Tags: python

I'm trying to identify the callers from one same line. Below is a example:

```
def get_file():
    caller_id = get_caller_id()
    return open(caller_id, 'a+')

def write_content():
    with get_file() as f1, get_file() as f2: # line with multiple callers
        f1.write('123')
        f2.write('456')

def fun():
    write_content()
    write_content()
    write_content()
    write_content()
    write_content()
```

The function `get_caller_id()` is what I want. It will generate two different `id`s for the first and the second `get_file()` calls in function `write_content()`, but for all the 5 calls of `write_content()` in function `fun()`, each of the two `get_file()` calls will return one same file's object among these 5 `write_content()` calls.

After calling `fun()`, there will be only two files generated, one with content '123123123123123' and the other with '456456456456456'. The returned `caller_id` can be consistent only for current running session and it doesn't matter if the `caller_id` is inconsistent after python kernel restarted.

I have tried `inspect` module:

```
def get_caller_id():
    cur_frame = inspect.currentframe()
    caller_frame = inspect.getouterframes(cur_frame)[2]
    frame_obj = caller_frame[0]
    line_no = caller_frame[2]
    return '{}_{}'.format(id(frame_obj), line_no)
```

When there is only one `get_file()` call in a line, this `get_caller_id()` works well. But for multiple callers from same line, it will generate same id, which is not what I want.

I have searched how to get caller's column position in a line, but found nothing. Is this kind of locating possible?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

The following is actually what I'm doing:

```
class AutoSharedParams(object):
    def __init__(self, dict_key='root', params_dict=None, init_value=None):
        if params_dict is None:
            params_dict = {}
        self._params_dict = params_dict
        self._dict_key = dict_key
        if self._dict_key not in self._params_dict and init_value is not None:
            self.x = init_value

    def __call__(self, init_value=None, func=None):
        caller_frame = inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1]
        caller_id = id(caller_frame[0])
        caller_ln = caller_frame[2]
        key = '{}_c{}_l{}'.format(self._dict_key, caller_id, caller_ln)

        if key not in self._params_dict:
            if func:
                init_value = func()
        else:
            init_value = None

        return AutoSharedParams(dict_key=key, params_dict=self._params_dict, init_value=init_value)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return False

    @property
    def x(self):
        if self._dict_key in self._params_dict:
            return self._params_dict[self._dict_key]
        else:
            return None

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._params_dict[self._dict_key] = value
```

and I use `lasagne` to create CNNs (`asp` is an instance if `AutoSharedParams`):

```
with asp(func=lambda: lasagne.init.HeNormal(gain='relu')) as w:
    l = Conv2DLayer(l, num_filters=16, filter_size=(3, 3), W=w.x)
    w.x = l.W

with asp(init_value=0) as w, asp(init_value=0) as b: # there are two calls in one line
    l = Conv2DLayer(l, num_filters=16, filter_size=(3, 3), W=w.x, b=b.x)
    w.x = l.W
    b.x = l.b
```

I have plenty of similar but different codes like above, and I want to share those created params (`w.x`, `b.x` and many others) when this code is going through again. A simplest way to do so is `list.append(w)` and `w=list.pop(0)`, but it would not compatible when there are different paths in the code. So I need a key to mark them.

Comment: What are you actually trying to *achieve* with this? Why would the functionality differ according to what's calling the function, and wouldn't that make it more-or-less impossible to test?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm actually creating many objects at many different places, and want them to be automatically stored and shared the next time this function is called. These variables are saved to and restored from a dictionary, and the key used in this dictionary is `caller_id` of the call which creates corresponding variable. Of course I can assign a key for each variable manually, but that would be redundant and I can't guarantee the key not duplicated.

Comment: Have you considered using a decorator to attach them to the callers instead? Could you give a clearer example, as I suspect an XY problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks. I don't know how decorator can help about this. I just added to the question some details about what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def f():
    curframe = inspect.currentframe()
    curframe = inspect.getouterframes(curframe, 2)
    caller = curframe[1][3]
    if caller == 'f1':
        print "f() called f1()"
    elif caller == "f2":
        print "f() called f2()"
    else:
        print "f() called by an unknwon!"


>>> def f1():
    f()

>>> def f2():
    f()

>>> def f3():
    f()
```

Works as below:

```
>>> f1()
f() called f1()
>>> f2()
f() called f2()
>>> f3()
f() called by an unknwon!
>>>
```

Modify `f()` to have different behavioral for different callers.

Comment: Thanks, EbraHim. Sorry for my unclear description in question. I can already locating the line num of caller, but if there are multiple calls in one line, I don't know how to distinct them in the callee.